# Does USB3.0 support reverse polarity in SSTX and SSRX?

Tags: usb, differential, polarity

Is it possible to Sawp the +/- pins of SSRX and SSTX to make the routing easier and avoid using vias? Does USB3.0 support this reverse polarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section 6.4.2 of the USB 3.x specification, the superspeed lanes support automatic "Lane Polarity Inversion". The receivers must detect an inversion during the training sequence and automatically correct for it if detected.

The _p and _n can therefore be reversed during routing as you suggest, as this constitutes a polarity inversion which is automatically corrected in the receiver.

For Gen1 this is done during TSEQ ordered sets.

> If polarity inversion
> has occurred, the D10.2 symbols within the TSEQ ordered set will be received as D21.5 instead of
> D10.2 and the receiver shall invert the polarity of the received bits.

For Gen2 a similar check is done during the SYNC training sets.

Comment: Wait, polarity inversion is just 180° phase shift on these lines, isn't it? In presence of unknown length, the receiver would have to deal with arbitrary phases, anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Not so, polarity inversion specifically occurs when swapping N and P with each other (cross over within the pair). Both P and N should be routed to have close to the same length so the phase between them remains at close 180 to degrees at all lengths. When bending around a corner you'll see wobbles on the inside trace to correct for the deviation in phase caused by inside trace otherwise covering less distance in the bend.

Comment: Yes, but swapping p and n just means that you invert the differential voltage. The same would happen without swapping, with a cable that is 180° longer?

Comment: @MarcusMüller no  it wouldn't. You'd just receive the bitstream a little bit later but with exactly the same differential voltage. The receivers use clock data recovery to detect the phase of a bit transition relative to some reference clock which would remove the extra delay anyway. Even if we play along and assume that 360 degrees is one bit period, consider the bit stream 111010, shifting by 180 degrees would not get you 000101 - consecutive 1's are not going to be inverted by a phase shift.

Comment: doh, I just realized I was considering USB ss as a bandpass signal on some carrier frequency, which it decidedly is not...